# How to use atomic_fetch_add_explicit to replace OSAtomicIncrement32?

Tags: c++

I have these two lines of code in my app

```
volatile __block int32_t counter = 0;
```

and later in a loop...

```
 OSAtomicIncrement32(&counter);
```

But now `OSAtomicIncrement32` is deprecated and Xcode is showing me this error message.

> 'OSAtomicIncrement32' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 -
>   Use atomic_fetch_add_explicit(memory_order_relaxed) from 
>   instead

See this error message, there is one parameter to `atomic_fetch_add_explicit`, right?

So I try

```
atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter)
```

and I see this message

> Too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 1

I love the crappy messages Xcode dumps.

How do I use this?

Comment: Just use `std::atomic`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_fetch_add)... It takes the pointer to the target variable, the number to add (in your case probably 1) and the memory order, suggested by the compiler as `memory_order_relaxed`, probably to match the existing behavior of `OSAtomicIncrement32`.

```
atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
```

If you don't know what a memory order is, probably you'd be better served by a plain `atomic_fetch_add` with the "safest" sequential ordering.

```
atomic_fetch_add(&counter, 1);
```

---

That being said, if you are actually working in C++ and that variable is used only by your code, you can just use an `std::atomic_int` (or `std::atomic<std::int32_t>` if you want guaranteed 32 bit range) and the plain `++` operator.

```
std::atomic_int counter{0};

//...

++counter;
```

Comment: @SombreroChicken what does `size_t` miss compared to `int`, `double` or even `ptrdiff_t`?