# OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier deprecated, how to solve this issue?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, deprecated

i'm trying Parse server on my ios app using Xcode14 and ios 16, I installed the pod Parse, but when I run the code I get the following warning message:

```
'OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use atomic_fetch_add() from <stdatomic.h> instead
```

Any help how I could fix this issue:

```
+ (instancetype)taskForCompletionOfAllTasks:(nullable NSArray<BFTask *> *)tasks {
    __block int32_t total = (int32_t)tasks.count;
    if (total == 0) {
        return [self taskWithResult:nil];
    }

    __block int32_t cancelled = 0;
    NSObject *lock = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *errors = [NSMutableArray array];

    BFTaskCompletionSource *tcs = [BFTaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource];
    for (BFTask *task in tasks) {
        [task continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *t) {
            if (t.error) {
                @synchronized (lock) {
                    [errors addObject:t.error];
                }
            } else if (t.cancelled) {
                OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier(&cancelled); // error is here
            }

            if (OSAtomicDecrement32Barrier(&total) == 0) { // error is here
                if (errors.count > 0) {
                    if (errors.count == 1) {
                        tcs.error = [errors firstObject];
                    } else {
                        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:BFTaskErrorDomain
                                                             code:kBFMultipleErrorsError
                                                         userInfo:@{ BFTaskMultipleErrorsUserInfoKey: errors }];
                        tcs.error = error;
                    }
                } else if (cancelled > 0) {
                    [tcs cancel];
                } else {
                    tcs.result = nil;
                }
            }
            return nil;
        }];
    }
    return tcs.task;
}
```

[image: err]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53979141/1187415.

Answer (score 1):

C11 has [support for atomics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) so you can do something like:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

// Declare an atomic int and initialize it to zero
atomic_int total;
atomic_init(&total, 0);

// Note: C17 and C23 allow safe direct initialization
// i.e. atomic_int total = 0;

// Operations such as ++total and --total are atomic
++total;

// Or alternatively
atomic_fetch_add(&total, 1);
atomic_fetch_sub(&total, 1);
```